# can we install SharePoint 2016 in Windows server 2012 standard but not 2012 R2?

Tags: installation, 2016

can we install SharePoint 2016 in Windows server 2012 standard but not 2012 R2?

we are getting error while installing SP 2016 RTM on WS 2012 Standard Edition.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install SharePoint you will need to have either Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2016 as operating system. Windows Server 2012 standard is not supported.

> One of the following server operating systems:
>
> - Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard or Datacenter
> - Windows Server 2016 Standard or Datacenter

Reference: [Hardware and software requirements for SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: that well explained.